# How to DataBinding and not appear in gridview

Tags: c#

When you bind data, data is displayed, but there are cases where only the binding is done and the grid view is not displayed. I ask you questions because I wonder how to do it.

I made this source to bind the data and not display it in the grid view.
Please let me know if you have any other good option
Note that visible should not be false to make the entire grid view invisible. We have to make sure that the data is not visible

`gridControl1.DataSource = db.GetDataView("TB_HIS", query);`
`gridView1.SelectAll();`
`gridView1.DeleteSelectedRows();`

Comment: I did not underetand why you are going to invisible the data while you are binding?

Comment: To use when entering or deleting values while empty

Comment: Not sure the use case is clear. Generally, when you BIND data, you want it shown and synced, that is the whole reason for binding. Can you share some additional details? My thinking goes like "if you do not want the data shown, do not bind it"

Comment: @dusdb Using a DataGridView to Enter and Delete database values is possible but not great design Try this select data from DGV display on another form with a Delete Button Use the same form to enter new data and show a Save Button All this is controlled from a Menu Form Use DGV to View all data